# TextView gets truncated when cell is reused

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I’m developing a “chat like” application, that has a **tableView** in it, which cells are containing a **view** and a **textView** inside each.

I set the view’s leading constraint so, that it can expand up to 75% only.

Sometimes when a cell gets reused, it calculates wrong width / height for the view, and the text gets truncated.

**Example:**

> Hello -> He...

[image]

Why is it so?

Project that reproduces the issue: https://github.com/krptia/BubbleBug2

Tested on iPhone 8 Plus simulator

## UPDATE

This issue might be occurring due to the wrong calculation with fractions.

(If I replace the 75% constraint with a leading-constraint: 100pt one, everything works fine)

But using pt does not look good on all screen sizes.
**Illustration:**

[image]

Comment: After running many times, I do not see a truncated trail. However, sometimes, a box is sometimes bigger than it should be but reloads when it exits and then re-enters the view.

Comment: @George_E sorry, updated the main post. I used iPhone 8 Plus simulator for the testing, and the bug appears when you scroll down.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding   cell.layoutIfNeeded() in cellforrow method before you return the cell

Comment: thank you for the response! i've tried it already, no changes :/ after a few scroll-down scroll-up some bubbles get cut of

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for this patch work, I have updated the tailing constraint from 0.25 to 0.26. Its is working fine for me.

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I assume with 0.26 there will be also another occourring, when the text would get cut off. /depending on its length/ so the problem is not with 0.25, it is with that the iOS is unable to handle fractions in this situation. :( But thank you for your response!